# python tkinter window positioning

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using tkinter to create a popup from within a plug-in for another program. The issue is that with two monitors, if the program I call the plug-in from is on the left monitor then the popup shows up on the right one.

OS is windows, but I would like to be able to use this for both windows and linux

Any way I can fix this so that the popup displays in front of the program?

code sample

```
    class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
```

called by

```
root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

image of issue:
[image]

Comment: Show a minimal example, possibly with screenshots of your issue

Comment: Also, what OS are you on?

Comment: edited, but os is windows but would like support for linux (Ubunutu specifically) as well

Comment: have you tried using `Tk.geometry` to position the window?

Comment: I know how to change the position, but how do I get the position of the program that is calling it?

Comment: do you have a python handle to the parent window? is it a TK window or something else? if its something else the answer is a bit more involved but if its a TK window you can call Tk.geometry with no arguments to get the current geometry, and then use that to center your new window over the old